# Run precompiled C program

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I am currently working on a program that is encrypting a text file. I made it in Turbo C++, using C language, but my main problem is that:

I need to run turboc++, in order for my .exe program to run. Does anybody here know a way to compile it and run it as stand-alone program?

Comment: rerun it in gcc? What's the difference with this C language by using Turbo C++ than traditional C?

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571076/how-to-compile-a-c-program) will help.

Comment: Turbo C++ doesn't spit out an .exe?

Comment: Turbo C does have the capability to produce an executable out of it, See [here](https://codingfox.com/12-21-creating-executable-file-in-turbo-c/), but no one actually prefers using Turbo C++ anymore since it is almost 32 years old...

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition is a great IDE and Microsoft is working hard on C++17 and some C++20 features. Download page for this free version of Visual Studio is https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TurboC++ is an *obsolete* compiler** for an obsolete variant of C++ or of C. Use a recent compiler (such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) 8 or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) 7; both are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) so freely available) for recent C11 or C++14 (or C++11) standards. **Get rid of TurboC++** since it is **obsolete** (and is not a good compiler, compared to other existing ones).

If using GCC, you'll compile your C file `foo.c` [using](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -g -O foo.c -o foo`. If using Clang, you'll compile with `clang -Wall -g -O foo.c -o foo`. Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info. You'll get an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) `foo` which can be run without having the source code. That executable is specific to your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and to your [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).

> I need to run turboc++, in order for my .exe program to run.

With any good enough C or C++ compiler, you don't need the compiler to run the executable it is producing.

Don't confuse a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) with the [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) you'll use to write C or C++ source code. All C or C++ compilers I heard of are [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) programs, that might be run from a terminal, an IDE, a good source code editor (such as [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/)).

If your source is in C++, that is `bar.cc`, use `g++ -Wall -g -O bar.cc -o bar` or `clang++ -Wall -g -O bar.cc -o bar`

Adapt these compilation commands (I'm giving those for Linux) to your operating system. On Windows, executables have a file path ending with `.exe`.

Of course, both GCC and Clang are able to compile and [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) a program made of several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Learn to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, such as [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/). Such tools are driving compilation and linking commands.

If you are learning to program in C++, be aware that it is a very difficult programming language (you'll need years of efforts to master it). And notice that Linux is a very developer-friendly [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), mostly made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code you could study. That is why I recommend Linux for those learning C++ or C.

PS. If your teacher requires TurboC, I do recommend to have a polite discussion with him, suggesting to make your homework with GCC or Clang.

Comment: Hmmm. Ill try to install gcc but wont get rid of tc++ for now atleast, because it is the ide that our professors are requiring us to use.

Comment: I believe you should dare discuss that TurboC++ requirement with your professors. In 2019 it is irrational

Comment: I agree. But I ve already been holding that grudge the entire school year and just a few more days and we're done. Thank you for the answer